# Как удалить символ " " из ArrayList содержащего char элементы

Tags: java, arraylist, char

```
ArrayList<Character> soglas = new ArrayList<>();
```

содержит:
`М м   м л   р м`.
Нужно, что бы стало:
`М м м л р м`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При помощи стримов:

```
List<Character> result = list
            .stream()
            .filter(c -> !Character.isSpaceChar(c))
            .collect(toList());
```

До `java 8` это делается обычным циклом:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        if (Character.isSpaceChar(list.get(i)))
            list.remove(i);
```

Comment: спасибо, так нормально отработало

Answer (score 2):

Можно по разному. Если нет ограничения только на 7-ую яву, то можно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21368638/3212712):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("How are you",
                                                  "How you doing",
                                                  "Joe",
                                                  "Mike"));
list.removeIf(s -> !s.contains("How")); //убрать все строки без How
```

В вашем случае, согласно @Artem Konovalov, можно [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/605670/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D0%B7-arraylist-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-char-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B/605675#comment824816_605675):

```
list.removeIf(Character::isSpaceChar); //убрать каждый char, если он пробел
```

---

Если же используется 7 ява, то можно вот так с помощью `rxJava`:

```
List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>() {{
    add('a');
    add(' ');
    add('b');
    add(' ');
    add('c');
}};
Observable.from(characters)
        .filter(new Func1<Character, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(Character character) {
                return !Character.isWhitespace(character);
            }
        })
        .toList()
        .subscribe(new Action1<List<Character>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(List<Character> characters) {
                System.out.print(characters);
            }
        });
```

Если ещё и `RetroLambda` подключить, то можно короче:

```
List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>() {{
    add('a');
    add(' ');
    add('b');
    add(' ');
    add('c');
}};
Observable.from(characters)
        .filter(character -> !Character::isWhitespace)
        .toList()
        .subscribe(characters -> System::out);
```

Comment: removeIf(Character::isSpaceChar);

Comment: ругается на метод removeIf

Comment: версия java какая?

Comment: седьмая получается, если 1.7

Comment: не будет работать. Метод removeIf появился в версии 1.8

Comment: понял, спасибо, сейчас попробую версию обновить

Comment: @enotdk, добавил как можно на 7 яве сделать в стиле стримов 8 версии с использованием `rxJava`

Answer (score 0):

Пробегаешься по списку, если текущий элемент ' ' - удаляешь его soglas.remove([текущий индекс])

Comment: `for(Object listElement  : soglas)
        {
            if (listElement.equals(" "))
                soglas.remove(listElement);
        }`

Comment: не работает так

Comment: проверяй на пробел через метод символа .isWhitespace()

Comment: @sscream, не поэтому не работает.